Why do Americans not say "and" when saying particular years?
Why do Americans not say "and" when saying particular years?
For example, here in the UK, for 2010, we'd say "two thousand and ten", but in the US, they would say "two thousand ten".
Why is that?

Why do both Americans and Brits not include an 'and' between thousands and hundreds? 'Two thousand three hundred' not 'Two thousand and three hundred'. But 'Three hundred fifty-two' [US] = 352 = 'Three hundred and fifty-two' [UK]. I don't think there's a logical explanation for these things.

Particularly with the years following after 2000, there was little clear guidance for what people should do since it was a long time since 1000. So people just had to make it up.

I think most Americans actually say "twenty-ten".

Brits are already evenly split as regards the article between monthname and ordinal date within month (Americans got solidly behind the article-less format for that one long ago) But pointless words tend to get discarded, so doubtless BrE will follow AmE for "century - decade" eventually.

And during the first decade, many would say "twenty-oh-nine". Although the movie was "Two thousand one: A Space Odyssey".

Voice of America recommends "two thousand nine" for years up to 2009, but says you can use either "two thousand eleven" or "twenty eleven" for 2011 and after; no mention of 2010.

@FumbleFingers Now if we could only get them to stop saying "boot".

@Barmar I've found 'Stanley Kubrick told journalists to pronounce the "2001" in "2001: A Space Odyssey" as "two thousand and one" in the hope that the movie would influence the pronunciation of that year.' [reddit] AFAIK, it's always been pronounced that way in the UK.

How well did that work? @EdwinAshworth

It isn't just years. If you ask how many things there are an American will say "two thousand ten" and a Brit way say "two thousand and ten".

@Barmar In the UK, it's the norm.

Twenty-ten. Time is money. I want the date, not a Proust novel.
